# How do I search to see if a MySQL user exists on the system?

Tags: mysql

I'm not finding a user by `show grants for 'username'@'localhost''` I'm thinking that perhaps the username is slightly different, so I want to do a wildcard search of all the database users. How can I do this?

**update:** for clarification, as I'm thinking maybe I've not been 100% clear. by wildcard I meant I wanted to be able to search for only part of the users name, or for all users who's name matches pattern. On the system I needed this on there were 5k+ users, and although that's not performance loss huge, I don't want to look through them one at a time either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to [@matthewh](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/290/matthewh)'s [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/682/how-do-i-search-to-see-if-a-mysql-user-exists-on-they-system/684#684) I managed to compose a query that would work when searching through a large number of users:

```
use mysql;
select  User, Host from  user where User like 'user%';
```

**Note:** `<user>` is whatever component of the username you need to search for, you may need a % on both sides if you don't know the start of the username, also <> are merely to note the variable, don't include them in an actual query, unless the username includes < or >.

Answer (score 7):

```
use mysql;

select Host,User from user;
```

will give you all the MySQL users on that server.

Comment: I voted this down one, because it doesn't do what I meant with by wildcard, though I acknowledge that may have been my fault for not being clear enough up front. It might have been interpretted as everything when what I wanted was the equivalent of `find -name 'user*' for a filename on unix.